# Javascript: JSON with multiple matches using lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lodash

Suppose I have an array that looks like this :

```
var users = [{
    users : [{
        user :'harry'
    }, {
        user : 'potter'
    }, {
        user : 'jinny'
    }, {
        user : 'weasly'
    }],
    age : 36,
    active : true
}, {
    users : [{
        user : 'brad'
    }, {
        user : 'pit'
    }, {
        user : 'angelena'
    }, {
        user : 'joly'
    }],
    age : 40,
    active : false 
}];
```

From this, I want to select objects based on a condition `users`, that can match multiple values

For example, if the names are `harry` and `angelena`, the output becomes this :

```
{
    users : [{
        user : 'harry'
    },{
        user : 'potter'
    }, {
        user : 'jinny'
    }, {
        user : 'weasly'
    }],
    age : 36,
    active : true
}, {
    users : [{
        user : 'brad'
    } ,{
        user : 'pit'
    }, {
        user : 'angelena'
    }, {
        user : 'joly'
    }],
    age : 40,
    active : false
}
```

If the name is `harry`, the output becomes this :

```
{
    users : [{
        user : 'harry'
    }, {
        user : 'potter'
    }, {
        user : 'jinny'
    }, {
        user : 'weasly'
    }],
    age : 36,
    active : true
}
```

I know  [lodash filter with matches](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) can be used for this, but I don't how to apply it for this case.

Is there any javaScript or jQuery solution for this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't the key names in `users.users` be unique?

Comment: yes `users.user` its unique

Comment: But there are four keys that are all `user`, each with a different value.  JSON doesn't require unique keys, but does recommend keys to be unique (unless you have a valid reason otherwise).  JS will usually overwrite the previous value for a duplicated key.

Comment: Sry thats a typo,now i've fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
function search(usersCollection, targets) {
    return _.filter(usersCollection, function (usersObj) {
        return _.intersection(targets, _.map(usersObj.users, 'user')).length > 0;
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
search(users, ['harry', 'angelena'])
/* => [{ 'users': [{user:'harry'},{user:'potter'},{user:'jinny'},{user:'weasly'}], 'age': 36, 'active': true },
       { 'users': [{user:'brad'},{user:'pit'},{user:'angelena'},{user:'joly'}],   'age': 40, 'active': false }] */
search(users, ['harry'])
/* => [{ 'users': [{user:'harry'},{user:'potter'},{user:'jinny'},{user:'weasly'}], 'age': 36, 'active': true }] */
search(users, ['severus'])
/* => [] */
search(users, [])
/* => [] */
```

It works by filtering the `users` collection by first plucking only the names from each users group (using `_.map`) and finding names in common with the `targets` to search.  If there are names in common (`.length > 0`), then at least one target name has been found and the particular users group is included in the results.

This implementation may be inefficient if the targets/users lists are long.  If this is an issue, consider refining your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hello **i create two params arrays :**

```
var params1 = ['harry','jinny'];//params of the same users object
var param2 = ['potter','pit'];//params of both users objects
```

**i create the filter function to return the filtered array**.

Here filter the users array and into it i compare the parameters ,and finally i return the filtered array to the `res` array variable:

```
var res = users.filter(function(user){
     for(var i=0;i<user.users.length;i++){
            //below iterate into params1 or params2 array
            for(var x=0;x<params2.length;x++){
                if(user.users[i].user == params2[x]){
                  return user;
                }//end if
            }//end for

    }//end for

   });//end filter
```

Please open your console into your browser and paste the code there to see the results.
Hope helps,good luck.